# GreenDao error: Target entity has no primary key, but we need it for ToMany

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator

I have this piece of code

```
    Entity pokemonSpecies = schema.addEntity("PokemonSpecies");
    pokemonSpecies.setTableName("pokemon_species");
    pokemonSpecies.addIdProperty();
    pokemonSpecies.addStringProperty("identifier").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addIntProperty("genderRate").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addIntProperty("captureRate").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addIntProperty("baseHappiness").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addBooleanProperty("isBaby").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addIntProperty("hatchCounter").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addBooleanProperty("hasGenderDifferences").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addBooleanProperty("formsSwitchable").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addIntProperty("order").notNull();
    pokemonSpecies.addIntProperty("conquestOrder");

    Entity conquestWarriorTransformation = schema.addEntity("ConquestWarriorTransformation");
    conquestWarriorTransformation.setTableName("conquest_warrior_transformation");
    conquestWarriorTransformation.addBooleanProperty("isAutomatic").notNull();
    conquestWarriorTransformation.addIntProperty("requiredLink");
    conquestWarriorTransformation.addIntProperty("femaleWarlord");
    conquestWarriorTransformation.addIntProperty("pokemonCount");
    conquestWarriorTransformation.addIntProperty("warriorCount");
    Property conquestWarriorTransformationRankId = conquestWarriorTransformation.addLongProperty("transformedWarriorRankId").primaryKey().notNull().getProperty();

    Entity conquestTransformationPokemon = schema.addEntity("ConquestTransformationPokemon");
    conquestTransformationPokemon.setTableName("conquest_transformation_pokemon");
    Property conquestTransformationPokemonTransformationId = conquestTransformationPokemon.addLongProperty("transformationId").notNull().getProperty();
    Property conquestTransformationPokemonSpeciesId = conquestTransformationPokemon.addLongProperty("pokemonSpeciesId").notNull().getProperty();
    conquestTransformationPokemon.addToOne(conquestWarriorTransformation, conquestTransformationPokemonTransformationId);
    conquestTransformationPokemon.addToOne(pokemonSpecies, conquestTransformationPokemonSpeciesId);
    conquestWarriorTransformation.addToMany(pokemonSpecies, conquestTransformationPokemon, conquestTransformationPokemonTransformationId, conquestTransformationPokemonSpeciesId).setName("pokemonSpecies");
    pokemonSpecies.addToMany(conquestWarriorTransformation, conquestTransformationPokemon, conquestTransformationPokemonSpeciesId, conquestTransformationPokemonTransformationId).setName("conquestWarriorTransformations");
```

I tried to make a n:m relation with PokemonSpecies and ConquestWarriorTransformation but the compiler gives me this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Target entity has no primary key, but we need it for ToMany 'conquestWarriorTransformations' from PokemonSpecies to ConquestWarriorTransformation
at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.ToManyWithJoinEntity.init2ndPass(ToManyWithJoinEntity.java:56)
at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Entity.init2ndPass(Entity.java:499)
at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Schema.init2ndPass(Schema.java:179)
at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.generateAll(DaoGenerator.java:92)
at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.generateAll(DaoGenerator.java:81)
at GreenDaoGenerator.main(GreenDaoGenerator.java:15)
```

It doesn't make sense because i have a primary key in ConquestWarriorTransformation:

```
Property conquestWarriorTransformationRankId = conquestWarriorTransformation.addLongProperty("transformedWarriorRankId").primaryKey().notNull().getProperty();
```

Comment: did you try using the `primaryKey()` method?